# How to go row wise and do calculation in an excel

Tags: vba, excel

```
Private Sub CalculateCharges()
Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
Dim i As Long
Dim temp As String
RowCount = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
ActiveSheet.Range("G1").Select
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
i = 0
While i < RowsCount
        If ActiveCell.Value Like "*W-M*" Then
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 8).Value = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 5).Value + ActiveCell.Offset(0, 6).Value
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
        End If
        i = i + 1
Wend
End Sub
```

The above is my piece of code. Below is my excel look alike. How I can add up 2 values if a cell contain specific text value in it

[image]

Comment: This can be done with a simple formula, is vba necessary?

Comment: Am going to develop this further for many sheets.

Comment: What is the error that's happening?  The code looks like it should run (although I would recommend not using select...see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros).  ActiveCell is finicky.

Comment: @AshwinBalajiKuppuraj have you tried the code below ?

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify your code, without selecting each cell, which slows you down on large ranges.

You can also use `InStr` function as well

```
Private Sub CalculateCharges()

Dim sht1 As Excel.Worksheet

Set sht1 = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

Dim i As Long
Dim temp As String

RowCount = sht1.UsedRange.Rows.Count

For i = 1 To RowCount
    If sht1.Cells(i, 6).Value Like "*W-M*" Then
    ' can use the InStr function instead
    'If InStr(1, sht1.Cells(i, 6).Value, "W-M", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
        sht1.Cells(i, 8).Value = sht1.Cells(i, 5).Value + sht1.Cells(i, 6).Value
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```